# When angular 2 final version will release

Tags: angularjs

I am asked to do my new task using angular js in my company. Now my question is can I use angular 2 release candidate to start the project or I have to wait for the angular 2 final release?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to wait - you can get started here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Comment: Of course you can start using it if you want to take the risk of using non-RTM code, that's up to you. As for when it will be released, only the Angular team can give some indication of that and they probably couldn't give a date themselves either. Also Angular 1.x will still work after 2 is released - it's not like a Windows 10 forced upgrade. One thing for sure tho, I certainly wouldn't recommend starting in Angular 1.x then moving to 2.x when it is released as they are so different.

Comment: Although in my opinion it is fine to start using Angular 2, you should ask your manager for approval to use Angular 2 RC for this project, especially if it is going to be production software. In my company, they said no, so development starting now has to be in 1.5